# Python 3.7.0 and tcl/tk 8.6 crashing on Mac OS X 10.12.6

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to run a script under IDLE in a fresh install of Python 3.7.0 on a Mac running OS 10.12.6, but it appears to crash once it hits "root = Tk()".

The error generated is:

```
Process:               Python [877]
Path:                 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:            Python
Version:               3.7.0 (3.7.0)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        Python [872]
Responsible:           Python [877]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2018-08-08 08:58:47.934 -0400
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12.6 (16G1510)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        F9CEC001-40B2-1F01-C918-48794CEB9A07

Sleep/Wake UUID:       6743F7F2-F98A-4114-8742-809CF7F2C43B

Time Awake Since Boot: 22000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       5400 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSApplication _setup:]:    unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fba344e3f60'
```

abort() called
    terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

I have interrogated the tcl/tk library using:

```
print(root.tk.exprstring('$tcl_library'))
print(root.tk.exprstring('$tk_library'))
```

This reports the following:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/tcl8.6
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/tk8.6
```

This appears to be correct given the information on Python.org [here](https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/).
What should I be doing differently?

Comment: Crash how? What's the error? Show us a minimal program that causes the error. Where did you get python from? What bit width did you install?